# How does Abp gracefully inform users that a field of newly added data cannot be repeated?

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, abp

The way I write it now is like this, which feels inappropriate, but there is no better way to write it:

```
    public override async Task<ProjectDto> UpdateAsync(int id, CreateUpdateProjectDto input)
    {
        try
        {
            return await base.UpdateAsync(id, input);
        }
        catch (Exception ex) when (ex.GetType().Name == "DbUpdateException"
            && ex.Message.Contains("See the inner exception for details.")
            && ex.InnerException != null
            && Regex.IsMatch(ex.InnerException.Message, $"Duplicate entry(.*?)for key 'IX_abp_projects_Name'"))
        {
            throw new UserFriendlyException("Name should be unique!");
        }
    }
```